# How to use python-twisted-web2 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, reverse-proxy

I am new to python twisted and I just start trying to use python twisted. My purpose is to build a simple **reverse proxy** that supports **HTTP/1.1**, which requires module **web2**. But I find that `import twisted.web2` does not work...

I tried `python -c "import twisted.web2"`

Here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named web2
```

I am using python2.7 and I did see those web2 related files located in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/web2`

And I also tried re-install `twisted` and `python-twisted-web2`, but it does not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twisted Web2 never progressed beyond the experimental stage.  Development of the project was abandoned many years ago.  The source was removed from the upstream Twisted repository many years ago.

You do not want to use Twisted Web2.  Twisted Web includes client and server implementations of the HTTP/1.1 protocol.  You want to use Twisted Web.

Comment: By default is it HTTP1.0 or HTTP1.1 when inheriting from `twisted.web.http`